# I have a gallery of code, but must join it with the rest of my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery

This is the link of the independent gallery code: http://codepen.io/giuliachristie/pen/QbjypG/

```html
<section id="projects">
    <center>
        <div id="SectionTitle">Alguns trabalhos</div>
        <div id="line-black"></div>
    </center>
    <div id="col-md-3">
        <div class="grid">

            <li data-tags="Print Design">
                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img25" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li data-tags="Print Design, Logo Design">
                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img26" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li data-tags="Webdesign">
                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img25" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li data-tags="Print Design">
                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img25" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li data-tags="Blog, Gráfico">
                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img25" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li data-tags="Webdesign, Print Design">
                <figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img25" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <figure class="effect-zoe">
                <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png" alt="img25" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                    <p class="description">Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </center>
</section>
```

And this is the entire website: http://codepen.io/giuliachristie/pen/doPYmw/

Please someone help me!! The portfolio is giving me a headache!!
And how can i increase a filter menu? Separating the gallery images by topic, like webdesign, blog, graphic etc..

Comment: You have a `</center>` that shouldn't be there at the end of your HTML code, please correct that. Now, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately what you are asking is too broad in scope for anyone here to provide an answer... you need to narrow down the specific issues a lot more ...to code that can actually be put in the question

Comment: I need to add the gallery code to the website section #projects, but it always get wrong, looks so different, like i can't see the images, the height of the section does not track...